# RecursionError and pyinstaller .spec error

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller, tensor

Hi guys I write a program but program dont opening
can you help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk1Yq.png)

Comment: Hello. Please provide the code you have tried so far and a description of the problem you try to solve.

Comment: I use tensorflow keras machine learning data science library my program opening ın pycharm but be exe pyinstaller dont opening why

Comment: Have you written any code? If so, add it. Or else, it's not easy to help you with just an image.